# DropDownList inside an juiceui AccordionPanel dont keep viewstate

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

As described in title. Here is the markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat=server ID="sc1"></asp:ScriptManager>



    <juice:Accordion runat=server ViewStateMode=Enabled>
        <AccordionPanels>
            <juice:AccordionPanel runat=server Title=teste >
                <PanelContent>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat=server AutoPostBack=true>
                        <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </PanelContent>
            </juice:AccordionPanel>
            <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel1" runat=server Title=teste234 EnableViewState=true ViewStateMode=Enabled >
                <PanelContent>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat=server AutoPostBack=true EnableViewState=true ViewStateMode=Enabled>
                        <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </PanelContent>
            </juice:AccordionPanel>
        </AccordionPanels>
    </juice:Accordion>
```

A can´t figure why. Any DropDownList placed on the same page outside the Accordion behave as expected.

**[Updated 2014-02-25]**

Solution with trouble DropDownList: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18478143/JuiceUIDriveMeCrazy.zip

Comment: What behaviour are you having that makes you say that he DropDownList doesn't keep ViewState? Which DropDownList behaves like that? Both or the one that doesn't have an ID?

Comment: Both DropDownLists when i select 2012 after the postback 2014 is the current value

Comment: Some of your elements don't have IDs, have you tried setting an ID for all `runat="server"` elements? I tried a demo and I couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: Added a solution with fail code. Please help!

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I downloaded your solution and came up with a few weird scenarios. For example, ddl1 is not accessible in the default.aspx.cs, also the acPanel1.Controls.Count returns 0. For some reason the ddl inside the AccordionPanel are not loaded as objects of the page.